# Converting C++ OpenGL to Java/LWJGL

Tags: java, c++, opengl, buffer, lwjgl

I am following the book *OpenGL SuperBible: Sixth Edition*, and they work with C++ there, however I prefer to program in Java, I am doing quite good at mapping all functions, LWJGL is after all pretty straight forward, however now I have some concerns.

Given the following code in C++:

```
GLuint buffer;  //buffer id
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);   //generate an unique id
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);  //bind buffer
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 12 * 4, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);    //allocate data on GPU
void *ptr = glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);    //obtain memory pointer on GPU
memcpy(ptr, data, sizeof(data));    //copy data, which is an array of float[]
glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER); //done with copying
```

I made this Java code:

```
    abId = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, abId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(12).asFloatBuffer(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    FloatBuffer data;   //declares FloatBuffer object
    data = glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY, 12 * 4, null).asFloatBuffer();   //gets FloatBuffer to which we can write, allocate 12 floats * 4 [float length]
    data.put(0.25f).put(-0.25f).put(0.5f).put(1.0f)
            .put(-0.25f).put(-0.25f).put(0.5f).put(1.0f)
            .put(0.25f).put(0.25f).put(0.5f).put(1.0f); //put data, NOT backed by array
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER); //unmap the buffer
```

Everything seems pretty straightforward, I circumvent using an array of `float[]` by the `FloatBuffer`, this is not as important yet, but I wanted to know that I could get that technique to work.

However *one* thing concerns me, that is that I cannot pass `(ByteBuffer)null` as second argument into `glBufferData`, as LWJGL gets a `NPE` then.
So I've decided to allocate a buffer without elements, does this still follow the C++ idiom of putting `NULL` into there? Are there any performance concerns regarding this Java version vs the C++ version?

Comment: there is a bulk `put(float[],int,int)` method in float buffer (also a corresponding bulk get if you need it)

Comment: @ratchetfreak With that one you need to create a backing `float[]`, which is not what I want.

Comment: Who downvoted and **why**? Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would be a slight performance penalty as it'll likely copy data that you won't use into the allocated buffer.

You can try LWJGL's `glBufferData(int target, long data_size, int usage)` it should be the C equivalent of `glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 12 * 4, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);`

Like this:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 12 * 4, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can populate the buffer you pass in so you don't need to map:

```
abId = glGenBuffers();
FloatBuffer data = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(12).asFloatBuffer();   //allocates FloatBuffer object
data.put(0.25f).put(-0.25f).put(0.5f).put(1.0f)
        .put(-0.25f).put(-0.25f).put(0.5f).put(1.0f)
        .put(0.25f).put(0.25f).put(0.5f).put(1.0f);
data.flip();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, abId);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```